# Jquery toggle system with two div in different locations

Tags: jquery, toggle

I would like to do this system : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/AzDQm/4/)

```
$(".more").click(function(e) {

    if( $(this).hasClass("open") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    } else {
        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 
        $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
    }

});
```

But with two div that aren't one after the other. What should I change, in this code, to make it work when two elements are placed in two different locations ?

In this situation for example :

```
<div class="column w50percent">
    <button class="more closed">Demande de devis</button>
</div>
<div class="column w50percent">
    <button class="more closed">Prise de contact</button>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of depending on the positional relation(siblings in this case) between current element and the rest related element have use an external reference(the more class)

```
var $els = $(".more").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
        $els.not(this).filter('.open').removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6QTg8/)

Also use `toggleClass()` instead of using add & remove class twice

Update:

```
var $els = $(".more");

if (Modernizr.touch) {
    $els.hammer();
}
var $els = $(".more").on(Modernizr.touch ? 'tap' : 'click', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $els.not(this).filter('.open').removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
});
```

Comment: This code work great on PC ! Thank you very much ! Argh but the toggleClass function don't work on touch device :-( Why ?

Comment: you may have to use a touch library... because the click event may not be firing

Comment: Ok thank you so much, I used Modernizr and Hammer for that. But how to reduce repetition in my code ? I post an answer for my question for the details.

Comment: Super ! Your code works perfectly, thank you again for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Thank you again, the code of Arun P Johny runs perfectly now. To make it compatible with touch devices I used Modernizr with Hammer. But how to reduce repetition in my code please ?

```
if(Modernizr.touch){
var $els = $(".more").hammer().on("tap", function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $els.not(this).filter('.open').removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
});
 } else {
var $els = $(".more").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $els.not(this).filter('.open').removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misreading this, every item you wish to affect has the class "more". In that case, you can simply replace the $(this) in most cases with the class name. So, your code would be ...

```
$(".more").click(function(e) {
    $('.more').removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    $(this).addClass('open');
   }
});
```

This simply removes that "open" class from all items of class "more" and then applies the "open" class to the item clicked on.